# Is there a portable shared memory mechanism in Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform, ipc, shared-memory

We are looking for a shared memory mechanism to transfer large amounts of data between processes without copying, in Java. It has to be portable (including Windows). Is there such a thing? We were thinking about using mmap-ed files, as they are portable, however their contents are written to disk which is not desirable. Are there alternatives? 
Otherwise, Windows has page-file-backed sections; is there an easy way to use these in Java? We are probably ok if we can use some other shared memory mechanism on *nix and those on Windows.

Comment: That sounds too low-level for normal Java to me... But I just might not be aware of Java's full capabilities

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of solutions in [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT).  These support a rolling queue which can read and written to concurrently, and a SharedHashMap which is entirely off heap.  In Linux you can "write" to a tmpfs filesystem and on Windows you can use a Ramdrive.

These libraries support replication between machines over TCP.  (The replication for Chronicle has been used for a while but for SharedHashMap, replication is still in beta)

While this is portable across OSes, it uses some features internal to OpenJDK/HotSpot JVMs and so it doesn't work on the IBM JVM AFAIK.

Note: the libraries support reading and writing data using a forma of serialization which doesn't create garbage, or using in place, off heap data structures. i.e. you don't need to deserialize the whole object to access a portion of it.